# How to create PhoneGap App with ADT 20?

Tags: android, cordova, adt

I try to do follow this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

but it can't work and return message `"Unfortunately,appname has stopped"`.

error [here](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg10/scaled.php?server=10&filename=phonegap.png&res=landing).

Someone can help me?
I'm beginner.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing enough information. Try to take a look at the log/error messages and stack trace in the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS) (the button in the top right corner in your Eclipse).

Comment: error in log cat  
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg10/scaled.php?server=10&filename=phonegap.png&res=landing

Comment: It seems that you're missing <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in the Manifest. The page you're referencing has it. Have you forgotten to add it in your code?